# geting fileds and data types of all members of a Object

Tags: java, generics

i have a method as follows.

```
test(Object obj){

}
```

now within this method i want to get all fileds along with the datatypes of those fileds.
How can i do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to use reflection. see [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) link from the Java tutorial.

keep in mind that reflection can be pretty expensive at runtime, so use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

As Omry suggested, you need to use Reflection. [Link 1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html)[Link 2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Using reflection is very resource intensive, violates almost all OOP principles and should be avoided unless really needed. It can get very nasty when you start accessing private data members/methods and violating the presentation invariants of the objects you're inspecting. Might i suggest using the *instanceof* operator to find out if your object is of a particular class and going from there?